Reading excel embedded image inside a cell in Apache PoI
I am trying to read data in an excel spreadsheet row by row and create a record for each row. Each row will have many cells containing data of types text, number and images. There can be multiple images and images can be placed over the cells or embedded within the cell.
I am using Apache PoI library to read excel spreadsheet. Apache PoI is doing great in reading the images which are placed over the cell but not able to recognize images which are embedded.

In the first approach, i tried reading images using XSSFSheet

public List<ImageData> getImages(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    return sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getShapes()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(xssfShape -> filterImages().apply(xssfShape, sheet))
                    .map(xssfShape -> extractImageData().apply((XSSFPicture) xssfShape, sheet.getSheetName()))
                    .toList();
}

public static BiFunction<XSSFShape, XSSFSheet, Boolean> filterImages() {
    return (shape, sheet) -> {
        XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor) picture.getAnchor();
        if (anchor.getCol1() == PAGE_COLUMN) {
            XSSFRow pictureRow = sheet.getRow(anchor.getRow1());
            if (pictureRow != null) {
                XSSFCell idCell = pictureRow.getCell(PAGE_COLUMN);
                return idCell != null;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    };
}

private static BiFunction<XSSFPicture, String, ImageData> extractImageData() {
    return (imageShape, sheetName) -> ImageData.builder()
            .filename(MessageFormat.format("{0}-Image{1}", sheetName, imageShape.getPictureData().getPackagePart().getPartName().getName()))
            .data(imageShape.getPictureData().getData())
           .contentType(imageShape.getPictureData().getPackagePart().getContentType())
                .size(DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)
                .sheetRowId(imageShape.getClientAnchor().getRow1())
                .sheetColId(imageShape.getClientAnchor().getCol1())
                .build();
    }


In the second approach, I tried using Workbook object to get the list of pictures.
This is listing all images (both embedded and images placed over the cell). However, i couldn't find the co-ordinates of the images (as in sheet name, row number and column number)

workbook.getAllPictures()

Question:
Is there a way to read embedded images using Apache PoI?
